# Co-registering multiple temporal orthomosaics?

Tags: envi, unmanned-aerial-vehicle, orthophoto

I have multiple (19) orthomosaics of the same approximate region taken regularly over the course of a couple months with a UAV.  Some, but not all, include ground control points we placed in the scene.  In all cases, however, there are features we can pick out that will be in the same position in each orthomosaic.  I need to co-register these images such that they are closely spatially matched.  They're currently within about 5 meters of each other, but I need to get that down to centimeters.

How do I go about doing that?

ENVI has the SPEAR change-detection tool that works on two images at a time.  I could step through all the images, one pair at a time, using this tool.

What other, potentially better, options are out there?

Here are two example images:

[image]

[image]

Comment: I am not familiar with ENVI but a quick web search returned results suggesting that ENVI has geofeferencing tools available.  Pick one image that is the most accurate in location and use this image and georeferencing to move the other images into the correct location.